# Algorithm for generating a triangular mesh from a cloud of points using kinect

Tags: c++, opencv, mesh, depth

I'm using OpenNI libraries (kinect) and OpenGL. I can catch the Depth from the kinect (using openni and opencv) and I can convert it in a ***cloud of points***.

So, i have 640*480 points in the 3D space and, for viewing purpose, i would like to generate a ***mesh composed of triangles.***

I need an algorithm that is simple but capable of representing walls and obstacles of every kind. What can you suggest me?

Comment: What do you mean by : "capable of representing walls and obstacles of every kind".
Maybe "Delaunay triangulation" is what you're searching for.

Answer (score 0):

Meshlab provides some algorithms to do this: Ball pivoting, Poisson triangulation and VGC. You can find implementations of them in the web.

Comment: PLC (Point Cloud Library) is in widespread use; it'd be worth investing time in it. Don't develop your own triangulation algorithm from scratch, especially if you'd rather devote your time to working on SLAM and related higher level problems.

Comment: hi, there are OpenGL functions that allow me to create a mesh from a point cloud?